# Getting JSON.parse unexpected character error

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am calling API with **fetch()** which delivers data in JSON form.When i try to execute below code snippet in Firefox console ,first statement runs succesfully but second statement get an error as i want to convert json to object using JSON.parse() .Why this happen?Can anyone explain please.

```
fetch('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/').then((result)=>console.log(result));

fetch('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/').then((result)=>{console.log(JSON.parse(result.body));});
```

The console result:

[image]

I tried  `fetch('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/').then(result => {return result.json()}) .then(console.log);` & it works .

Note that i am using a cors add-on to bypass the same origin policy.

Answer (score 2):

The promise returned by `fetch` resolves into a Response object, not a string containing the body of the response.

You can see that in your screenshot!

Use the Request object's `json()` method to get the body of the response and parse it as JSON.

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/')
console.log(response);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
```